# Incorrect syntax near @[parameter name] when using parameterised Alter Database command

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to drop a SQL Server database using the following code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("USE MASTER; ALTER DATABASE @database SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE @Database", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", TestingEnvironment.DatabaseName);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I execute it, I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@database'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common
>   table expression or an xmlnamespaces
>   clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon. Incorrect
>   syntax near 'IMMEDIATE'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

putting it simply the Alter Database command doesn't support parameters as you want it to. you'll have to concat strings here.

Comment: Mladen, That was the conclusion I came to. Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Params case sensitive? You have a capital D in the 2nd @Database.

Comment: Good thought, but actually that doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: And can you add a param twice like that, with one add param?
Might want to try using GO instead of ';'...